# C1189 #error: /RTCc rejects conformant code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022, wtl

I try to compile the following solution:

https://github.com/TimoKunze/EditControls

When I try to compile it using VS 2022, I am getting the following compiler error:

Error   C1189   #error:  /RTCc rejects conformant code, so it is not supported by the C++ Standard Library. Either remove this compiler option, or define _ALLOW_RTCc_IN_STL to acknowledge that you have received this warning.
EditCtls    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31721\include\yvals_core.h    1542

How could I get rid of this compiler error?

Here are my directories:

Include directories:
D:\Projects\Libraries\WTL\Include;$(IncludePath);$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\include

External Include Directories:
$(VC_IncludePath);$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath);

Library directories:
$(ProgramFiles)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10586.0\um\x86;$(LibraryPath);$(VSInstallDir);$(VSInstallDir)lib

Library WinRT directories:
$(WindowsSDK_MetadataPath);

Source directories:
$(VC_SourcePath);

I am pretty new with C++, and I don't know how to "define _ALLOW_RTCc_IN_STL to acknowledge that I have received this warning."

I also don't see that the /RTCs is defined anywhere in the project property page. Where would I find that?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm about 7 years behind you, but in VS 2015 that was hidden in Project->Properties->C/C++->Code Generation->Basic Runtime Checks

Comment: The path that @user4581301 gave is correct for VS 2022. I think by default the run time check is set to `Both` for `Debug` and `Default` for `Release`

Comment: Yes, either Basic Runtime Checks or Smaller Type Checks.

Answer (score 0):

As I found out from this https://adn-cis.org/forum/index.php?topic=7477.0 Problem with RTCc option of compiler.
So apparently there are 3 alternative solutions:

1. Do not install Update 2 for Visual Studio and subsequent ones (but they seem to greatly improve the performance of STL)
2. Remove the compiler option /RTCc (C++/code generations in settings)
3. Declare the _ALLOW_RTCc_IN_STL variable somewhere (I did it in preprocessor)